# Aginity search for the object browser

Tags: netezza

Aginity for Redshift has shows a search for the object browser, but I cannot find this in Aginity for Netezza (PureData Systems for Analytics).  Is this available?

Answer (score 0):

There is a search box at the bottom of the object browser pane.

You can find it documented in the ... [documentation](http://www.aginity.com/documentation/wb/nz/#Aginity_Topics/Aginity_Workbench/Searching_for_Database_Objects.htm).

[image]

Comment: I do not see the search box at the bottom of the object browser pane.

Comment: Perhaps you have an old version installed? The feature is clearly documented, and is obvious in the current version.  It is probably more appropriate to ask UI questions on Aginity's support forum for the product.